# How to setup Maven to generate regular as well as executable JAR files from a single POM

Tags: java, maven

I know how to setup Maven to generate a regular JAR file for my project with `mvn package`. I also know how to setup Maven to generate an executable JAR file with the same command. What I would like to be able to do is to generate a regular JAR file with `mvn package` and also generate an executable JAR file, either from the same command or with another `mvn` command. All setup in the same POM file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add below `plugin` into your `pom.xml`:

```
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.demo.MainTestClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

after adding this you need to run `mvn clean compile assembly:single` command from command line.